# How can i navigate back to the file i just opened in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a Keyboard shortcut to Navigate back to the file i was most recently viewing?

I understand there is `Ctrl + Tab` which will show recent files, but this doens't include ephemeral tabs.

I understand there is a setting to turn `preview` mode off. But i would like a shortcut that will bring back the ephemeral tabs once i have navigated away.

Comment: what's the context here? is the currently focused workbench part still and editor? or something else (like a view/panel)? is the very last action you performed to move focus away from that editor to something else? or do you want this to work even if you have done other things after moving focus away from that editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VS code, if you have navigated away from an ephemeral tab using the "Ctrl + Tab" shortcut, The default keybinding helping you to go to your ephemeral file once navigated away is is "Ctrl + Shift + Tab" on Windows and Linux, and "Cmd + Shift + Tab" on macOS.

This allows you to navigate back and forth between previosly activated tabs,even if some of them are ephemeral.

You can also customize the keybindings in VS code according to your preferences by going to the "File" menu, selecting "Preferences," and then choosing "Keyboard Shortcuts." In the keyboard shortcuts editor, you can search for specific commands, modify existing keybindings, or define your own custom shortcuts.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).